# Declare Array of Non-Nullables using Annotation-Based HotChocolate

Tags: hotchocolate

I can't figure out how to make it so that the elements of the array are non nullable using annotation-based HotChocolate. I'm looking to create a gql schema for my class that looks like:

```
foos: [Foo!]!
```

However, at the moment all I've been able to come up with for my class is:

```
class Bar
{
[GraphQLNonNullType]
public List<Foo> foos {get; set;}
}
```

I am using C# 9.0

Comment: Does your C# version support nullable reference types?

Comment: Yes it supports nullable reference types, I am using C# 9

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem!

While I was using C# 9, my project was *not* configured to enforce explicit nullability. I changed my .csproj configuration file to include the line

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

This has the added benefit of no longer needing to use the [GraphQLNonNullType] attribute anymore.  My new code looks like this:

```
class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> foos {get; set;}
}
```

Which generates the gql schema I am expecting.

If you don't want to change your entire project settings to achieve the same result,  here is another option.

```
class Bar
{
    #nullable enable
    public List<Foo> foos {get; set;}
}
```